# [ros2cli] How can I get launch files?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I get a list of all launch files (an equivalent to what `ros2 pkg executables` does for all executables)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296832/%5Bros2cli%5D-how-can-i-get-launch-files?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of the Bouncy release, the closest functionality to what you are looking for is that a list of launch files that are in a specific package will tab-complete once `ros2 launch <package_name>` has already been typed. There isn't currently an equivalent to `ros2 pkg executables` (the functionality [is there](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/9ee4cc65863ddc353decbd8f8f5fed6d425de5f0/ros2launch/ros2launch/api/api.py#L137) but it's currently only used for argument auto-complete), nor is there currently a way to list all packages that have launch files (see [this tracking issue](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/98)).

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2018-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-07-10**:
:+1: to dhood's answer.
One clarification: the functionality is not currently there as the current solution relies on crawling the file system and would not recognize any launchfile not named `*.launch.py` hence the issue referenced above to be able to register them explicitly in the index.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-10**:
I thought there will probably be some `list` sub command for `ros2 launch` as well. In some cases it is more convenient to have "command based" instead of "interactive" stdout output (e.g. for automation purposes). In case it get's relevant for me I'll checkout the issues again. Thx.